OpenGL Bindless with sampler2DArray, samplerCube etc
Every bindless texture example I can find uses sampler2D but is it possible to use samplerCube/sampler2DArray/sampler3d as well?
For example something like:
layout(bindless_sampler, location=0) uniform sampler2DArray bindless;

....
glUniformHandleui64ARB(0​, myTextureArray2D);

